# C++ method supposed to accept a pointer to pointer, recieves an adress and still works

Tags: c++, pointers

I am studying an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370994%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#summary) of how to create a simple Direct2D application and the author defines a class template and a method called `SafeRelease` as follows:

```
    template<class Interface>
inline void SafeRelease(
    Interface **ppInterfaceToRelease
    )
{
    if (*ppInterfaceToRelease != NULL)
    {
        (*ppInterfaceToRelease)->Release();

        (*ppInterfaceToRelease) = NULL;
    }
}
```

The code above is from the header file. The destructor for the class, however, makes these calls:

```
DemoApp::~DemoApp()
{
    SafeRelease(&m_pDirect2dFactory);
    SafeRelease(&m_pRenderTarget);
    SafeRelease(&m_pLightSlateGrayBrush);
    SafeRelease(&m_pCornflowerBlueBrush);

}
```

I just started learning c++ and I'm wondering how come these calls are legal. Obviously my understanding of pointers as procedure parameters is flawed, so please correct me. How can a procedure that accepts a pointer type accept an address? Also, Visual Studio cannot find the declaration of the `Release` method when I press F12, but I suspect it has something to do with the COM release method, so an explanation of what goes on inside it would be very helpful, since I can't "step into" it when debugging. So- the code works just fine, I'm just wondering why. Complete source code can be found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/d2ddrawrectangle/release/projectreleases.aspx).

Comment: The address-of operator `&` returns a pointer to the thing whose address was taken. So if the things here are pointers, all is fine.

Comment: and the notation convention m_pSomething suggests that they are pointers. m means class member, p means pointer

Comment: A pointer is an address and an address is a pointer. What distinction are you making? By the way, that sort of style is obsolete and dangerous. `std::unique_ptr` or the like would take care of safely destroying member pointers, handling exceptions or whatnot, and you wouldn't need an explicitly defined destructor at all.

Comment: The reference operator `&` returns the address of the variable it precedes. I understand the notation, and the fact that the variables in question are all pointers, but they are all preceded by the `&` and the will be resolved as addresses. The distinction I am making(I guess) is that this method should receive a pointer variable, not the addresses those pointers point to.

Comment: Scratch the last comment, I just realized what was wrong, because the `&` will return the address of the pointer variable, and not the address the pointer points to.. If anyone would like to make a simple answer to this, I will accept it. I understand it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to simplify things and basically just think of memory as being one gigantic array, where you have the address (which you could think of as being the index into the array), and then you actually have the contents itself (which can be anything).

So Interface ** can be thought of as the address pointing to memory which contains another memory address which contains an Interface object.

Imagine the following

```
 Name               Type               Memory Address           Contents

 interfacePtrPtr    Interface**        0x1                      The address 0x2
 interfacePtr       Interface*         0x2                      The address 0x3
 interface          Interface          0x3 - 0xFF?              An interface object
```

In this fictional example lets say we started with **interface**, then we used **&interface** to get our **interfacePtr**, and then used **&interfacePtr** to get interfacePtrPtr.

You could also go backwards and use *interfacePtrPtr to get interfacePtr, and then *interfacePtr to finally get back to the interface itself.

So in your example, when

```
  SafeRelease(&m_pDirect2dFactory);
```

is called, the function is being given the address of your interface pointer - an interface pointer pointer if you will.

```
  (*ppInterfaceToRelease)->Release();
```

What this then does is dereferences this pointer with the *, converting the pointer-pointer back into a regular pointer, and then uses the -> shorthand to dereference the pointer into the Interface object itself, and call its release method.

Hope this makes sense.